# unloading items from popup menu error

Tags: vb6, popupmenu

i have am getting this error

> "Unable to unload within this context"

when ever i try to unload a menu item from the popupmenu like his

```
For i = mnuTCategory.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
       Unload mnuTCategory(i)
Next
```

Is there any way to do this without this error>?

Thanks

Comment: According to your explanation and code example, your are unloading the very object that triggered the event. Am I correct?

Comment: the menu did not trigger the event, am unloading from a sub routine

Comment: OK. Were the mnuTCategory() menus created at run-time or through the VB6's IDE?

Comment: Also, what object triggered the event to execute the For/Next cycle to delete the menu items?

Comment: the first menu in the array ( 0 ) is created at design time, the rest (1 - 3) are created at runtime. Also a call to the subroutine that deletes the menu is made from the click even of a combo box

Comment: Are you perhaps triggering the For/Next cycle through a dropdown/combobox? If not, what or who is triggering it?

Comment: when an item is selected, the combo click event is fired. the selected item from the combo is used to delete the menu in the click event handler of the combo. what is your point, what are you trying to find out?

Comment: what is the value of i when the error occurs?

Comment: it occurs at the first loop, that is i is 3, as the menus contains 3 menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to remove controls from a `Form`, when triggered by a `ComboBox`, you will need to execute the deletion operation through a `Timer`.

So, when the `ComboBox` event is to be triggered, start (enable) a `Timer` that when triggered, calls the subroutine that you wanted to call in the first place.

This is how the code would look like:

```
Private Sub MyCombo_Change()
    MyTimer.Enabled = False
    MyTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub MyTimer_Timer()
    MyTimer.Enabled = False
    DeleteMenuItems
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteMenuItems()
    Dim i As Intener
    For i = mnuTCategory.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
       Unload mnuTCategory(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i haven't tried you code, but i used an alternate menu component

Comment: If you have the time, give it a try -- I have encountered this issue many times and, as far as I can tell, using a timer is the only solution. Thanks for accepting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

my test project below works without errors for me, does it work for you ?

```
'1 form with :
'    1 command button : name=Command1
'    1 main menu item : name=mnuMain
'    1 sub menu item  : name=mnuSub    index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = mnuSub.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Unload mnuSub(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = 1 To 3
    Load mnuSub(intIndex)
    mnuSub(intIndex).Caption = "Sub" & CStr(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```

### Edit

funny!
the testproject below gives the same error : it is indeed caused by calling the unload from an combobox ..

```
'1 form with :
'    1 combobox       : name=Combo1
'    1 main menu item : name=mnuMain
'    1 sub menu item  : name=mnuSub    index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Combo1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  With Combo1
    Select Case .ListIndex
      Case 0 'add
        For intIndex = 1 To 3
          Load mnuSub(intIndex)
          mnuSub(intIndex).Caption = "Sub" & CStr(intIndex)
        Next intIndex
      Case 1 'del
        For intIndex = mnuSub.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
          Unload mnuSub(intIndex)
        Next intIndex
    End Select
  End With 'Combo1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Combo1
    .AddItem "add"
    .AddItem "del"
  End With 'Combo1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this intrigues me but i can't find a cleaner solution than using another control, this control can be an control which you already have on your form, or a dummy control just for this purpose. you can then use the lostfocus event of the combobox

see the testproject below :

```
'1 form with :
'    1 combobox       : name=Combo1
'    1 textbox        : name=Text1
'    1 main menu item : name=mnuMain
'    1 sub menu item  : name=mnuSub    index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Combo1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  With Combo1
    Select Case .ListIndex
      Case 0 'add
        For intIndex = 1 To 3
          Load mnuSub(intIndex)
          mnuSub(intIndex).Caption = "Sub" & CStr(intIndex)
        Next intIndex
      Case 1 'del
        Text1.SetFocus
    End Select
  End With 'Combo1
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_LostFocus()
'use the lostfocus event to unload stuff
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = mnuSub.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Unload mnuSub(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Combo1
    .AddItem "add"
    .AddItem "del"
  End With 'Combo1
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
  Combo1.SetFocus
End Sub
```