# error while unloading dynamically created labels in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have generated some labels dynamically based on data in grid. when user read the data i show those labels again, But when user tries to edit the data i'm unloading all the labels and loading again depend on new data.But the Problem is when i tried to unload already loaded label the error says "UNABLE TO UNLOAD WITHIN THIS CONTEXT". only 0th index label is added on design time. with adding the label the properties of frame on which they are placed are also changes

```
For j = 0 To LbYarnName.UBound
    If j > 0 Then
        Unload LbYarnName(j)
        Unload LbMeter(j)
        Unload Lbissue(j)
        Unload LbBal(j)
    Else
        LbYarnName(0).Caption = "-"
        LbMeter(0).Caption = "-"
        Lbissue(0).Caption = "-"
        LbBal(0).Caption = "-"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422996/unloading-items-from-popup-menu-error  I don't have VB6 in my PC at the moment. Otherwise I could have replicated your issue and find out a solution!

Comment: No actually ! But i have adjusted my code to get it work as i want..but i still didn't understood what is that error

Comment: Glad to know that its resolved. If you found the solution, then you can help others who are facing similar issue by providing your solution as an ANSWER here. Btw, have a look at `vbforums.com` website. There's some VB6 gurus there!

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran  i changed the code from button click event to lost focus of a textbox, may be that was the issue, Thaks for the Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many places where an Unload method can't be used, specifically within several types of events.  The ones that have bitten me in the past are the .Resize and .Paint events of a form, but there are others, too.  Note that the prohibition on the Unload method extends to controls on the form, not just the form itself.

Microsoft lists several other places this error can be raised: [Unable to unload within this context (Error 365)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/unable-to-unload-within-this-context-error-365)

Comment: i did called the frame resizing with unloading on one of button click, seems that was the main problem